# Generate ZPL file to be used for printing

Tags: c#, .net, zpl-ii

We have to create a ZPL for the label we need to print. For now we are creating the ZPL file by appending tags as follows

```
^XA^CFD^PW584^FS
^PON^FS
~DGR:IMG1.GRF,15042,23,....
^FO250,770^XGR:IMG1.GRF,1,1^FS
^IDR:IMG1.GRF^FS
^XZ
```

Can we generate the ZPL file for our label automatically because presently we are facing different issues while creating ZPL as the printing is not happening correctly.

We are using Zebra Designer Pro to create the templates. Than we are flashing the template on the printer thru the printer IP. But we have to create ZPL to pass the parameters to the template which is creating an issue. Our template layout is very simple. Thanks is advance, as we are stuck at this problem.

Comment: i use the ZPL language of our Zebra Barcode printers in several projects, it works great and produces consistent results without having to worry about printer drivers. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The problem we are facing that the various values we are passing as parameters for different fields are getting misplaced. For ex if i have three fields than the value for one is appearing for another field

Comment: This sounds more like a layout issue. How do you create your label data (template file, source code...) and how do you send the label to the printer (ftp, text printer driver)?

Comment: We are using Zebra Designer Pro to create the templates. Than we are flashing the template on the printer thru the printer IP. But we have to create ZPL to pass the parameters to the template which is creating an issue. Our layout is very simple there is nothing more we can do in the template. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate ZPL for the label using Zebra Designer Pro. Please do the following:

Step1: Create the template:

Step2: Print the template:
After designing you template choose option to print the template and

[image: Prinitng ZPL To File]

Step3: Open the .prn file containing the ZPL for the template you have designed

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering as we were really stuck on the issue. But we are facing another issue while passing the parameters in the ZPL to the printer. Sometimes the data is getting misplaced and is not printing correctly on the printer though we have tried various options.

Comment: It sounds like that is a separate question.

Comment: Its always better to use the ZPL created by Zebra Designer Pro and you can do the same for passing the parameters as well. As Stefan it would be good to create another question for that and provide all the neccessary details

Comment: I have created the question at the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485250/zpl-passing-parameters-to-the-labels-prints-with-misplaced-data
Please check.